# How to make aritmetic operations from latest record to the previous one in Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I acomplished this when user make input like this:

```
$CalcPrevNumb = model::latest()->first();
$student = new model([
          'recordtime'             =>  $request->get('recordtime'),
          'obem_sprqmo_pr_den'     =>  $request->get('cname2') - $CalcPrevDay->cname2
        ]);
$student->save();
```

But now the goal is to do this when for example csv file is imported in to the DB(pgsql). Now I need to substract the last created and the previous one.

Something like this?

```
$CalcPrevNumb = model::latest()->first(); // not the latest but previous 
$students = model::whereBetween('recordtime', $dateScope)
->selectRaw('recordtime, cname2 - $CalcPrevNumb')
->orderBy('recordtime', 'ASC')
->get();
```

How to do this in Elequent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
  // create object for the prev day
    $user = model::whereBetween('recordtime',$dateScope)->selectRaw('recordtime')->first();
    
  // if no records for current day don't brake the code
    if($user === Null){
      $user = model::latest('recordtime')->first();
    }
    
    $CalcPrevDay = model::where('recordtime', '<', $user->recordtime)
    ->latest('recordtime')
    ->first();
    
    $students = model::whereBetween('recordtime', $dateScope)
    ->selectRaw('recordtime, (cname2 - ?) as obem_sprqmo_pr_den', [$CalcPrevDay->obem_m3])
    ->orderBy('recordtime', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

I tryed:

```
$students = model::whereBetween('recordtime', $dateScope)
->selectRaw('recordtime, (cname2 - :CalcPrevDay) as obem_sprqmo_pr_den', array('CalcPrevDay'=>$CalcPrevDay->cname2))
->orderBy('recordtime', 'ASC')
->get();
```

But error occurred:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters
```

Can't understand why but stick to my first solution. If someone have better solution will wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the skip and take methods to limit the number of results returned from the query or to skip a given number of results in the query

[Official Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#limit-and-offset)